# Paypal IPN how to get current session

Tags: php, session, paypal, paypal-ipn

I want to get my previous `$_SESSION['cart']` to the Paypal IPN

Sample of [**IPN Code**](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPN_PHP_41.txt) I use. Everything working fine and script got the `$_POST` data from Paypal.

```
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
        $subject = time();
        $to      = 'my@email.com';
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { 
        $body .= "\n$key: $value";
        }
        mail($to, $subject, $body); 
}
```

**Question**

```
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
 // 1. How to get my previous $_SESSION['cart'] here? 
 // 2. When I call my $_SESSION['cart'] here not ouput will come & it's empty.
 // 3. Or this code only to get $_POST data from Paypal website only?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't because IPN is notified outside of your checkout process. It essentially is a background operation separate from the ordering/payment process of your website. If there is information in that session that you need to access you will need to store it in a database and then include some kind of identifier with it that is also passed to Paypal. Email addresses are usually good but a unique token, like a hash of some kind, is probably better. Then when the IPN notification comes in with that identifier you can pull that information out of the database and use as needed.